# Когда предложения отделены двоеточием

Tags: синтаксис

Следующие предложения:

> (1) Он решил подумать: **кто знает, может, они и были бы счастлива
>   вместе.**
>
> (2) Она боялась другой беды: **ее муж узнает об измене.**
>
> (3) Он попросил сделать ему подарок: **весь вечер не заходить на кухню.**
>
> (4) Она всегда путала их обязанности: **садовника она послала на кухню,
>   а кухарку поливать цветы.**

Это были бы придаточные дополнительные в моем языке, которые отделяют запятой, не двоеточием (например, *он решил подумать о чем?* или *она боялась, чтобы ...*)
Как правильно рассматривать эти предложения в русском языке? Фрагменты после двоеточие это отдельные предложения или они находятся в зависимости от предыдущих предложений?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Просьба обратить внимание на два момента. В первом предложении "решил подумать" — так обычно в этом контексте не говорят, лучше просто "подумал". "Решил подумать" уместно, если человек сознательно решил потратить какое-то время на размышления о чём-то. В последнем предложении, скорее всего, должно быть "посылала" вместо "послала" (иначе "послала" плохо согласуется с "всегда путала").

Comment: @grizzly. Возможно, предложения составлены верно, если пофантазировать, в них можно найти смысл: (1) Он решил подумать, то есть повременить, не заявлять сразу, что их брак был обречен с самого начала:  кто знает, может, они и были бы счастлива вместе (если бы не злой рок).  (2) Она всегда путала их обязанности (и на этот раз тоже): садовника она послала на кухню, а кухарку поливать цветы.

Comment: @М_Г Я это всё понимаю, конечно (поэтому я и говорю "обычно, скорее всего" и т.п.). Я не писал бы тот комментарий, если бы автор вопроса был носителем языка.

Comment: @grizzly Я тоже написал скорее для автора вопроса, чтобы ей было понятно, какой смысл "спрятан" в этих  предложениях.

Comment: @grizzly. Я тоже обратила внимание на "решил подумать", это, как мне кажется,  в приведенном предложении неверное сочетание. Можно сказать: он решил подумать об этом позже, но если уже высказана конкретная мысль, то это, конечно), "он подумал". Второе предложение допустимо (М_Г объяснил почему). Я бы еще поставила там тире: Она всегда путала их обязанности: садовника она послала на кухню, а кухарку  – поливать цветы.

Answer (score 3):

В русском языке это **бессоюзные сложные предложения (БСП),** а двоеточие в БСП  ставится в том случае, если нужно выразить отношения **пояснения, изъяснения и др** между простыми предложениями, входящими в состав БСП.

Например: **Он подумал, что они должны быть счастливы.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным **изъяснительным**, изъяснительные отношения выражает союз ЧТО.

В Вашем языке это придаточные **дополнительные** (подумал о чём, сказал что).

Но когда союз пропущен, вместо запятой ставится **более сильный знак ― двоеточие** и меняется интонация (делается предупредительная пауза): **(1) Он подумал: (2) они должны быть счастливы.**

**Примечание:** Бессоюзная связь может быть между двумя простыми предложениями в составе БСП, но в сложное предложение могут входить и три простых предложения. Тогда бессоюзная связь будет между предложениями 1 и 2,3. (Но в каждом из этих предложений **должна быть предикативная основа**).

**Примеры:**

(1) Он решил подумать: (2) кто знает, может, они и были бы счастливы вместе.

(1)Она боялась другой беды: (2) ее муж узнает об измене.

(1) Она всегда путала их обязанности: (2)садовника она послала на кухню, а (3) кухарку (она послала) поливать цветы. Предложение (3) неполное.

**А это другой пример:**

Он попросил сделать ему **подарок (какой?)**: весь вечер не заходить на кухню.

Оборот на основе **инфинитива в роли несогласованного определения**, который обособляется с помощью тире или двоеточия.

Предложение считается простым **(одна предикативная основа**), осложненным обособленным оборотом.